# Configuration.ini file feature codes

Tags: sql-server

I have searched but not been able to find a list of the codes and descriptions available when using the configuration.ini file.

Is anyone able to link me some information?

Comment: Try `setup.exe /?`  from the command-prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to use the command line options documentation to review your different configuration options:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx

Whether they all translate exactly over to what's in the configuration file (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239405.aspx)?  That I couldn't answer.